# how to compare first row with N below rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

how we need to compare first row with below rows.
I have sample data

```
tbl_Name    Emp_cnt
Emp1         20
Emp1         20
Emp1         20
Emp2         22
Emp2         21
Emp2         20
```

how can I compare with below rows for employee name .If below rows are duplicate the need to show 'Y' condition otherwise 'N' condition.

Output :

```
tbl_Name    Emp_cnt condition
Emp1         20          Y
Emp1         20
Emp1         20
Emp2         22          N
Emp2         21
Emp2         20
```

can you please suggest on this one.

Comment: SQL tables have no "first" and "below" rows, as long as you don't specify an order.

Comment: Why should the *first* row have `Y` instead of the second or third? There's nothing that says one row should come before another. Is there something that can be used for ordering, eg an `ID` or date?

Comment: Rows in a database table are unsorted by nature. There is no "first" row.

Comment: What if the values were 20/21/21 ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff condition should come as N if all the three rows duplicate then Y condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion will bypass the question of a random sort order by a neat grouping:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE (EmpName VARCHAR(50), Emp_cnt INT)
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
('Emp1', 20),
('Emp1', 20),
('Emp1', 20),
('Emp2', 22),
('Emp2', 21),
('Emp2', 20);
```

--The query will return just one row per employee with a `Y` or an `N` depeding on having just one or more than one value within `Emp_cnt`:

```
SELECT EmpName
      ,CASE COUNT(DISTINCT Emp_cnt) WHEN 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS condition 
FROM @mockup 
GROUP BY EmpName;
```

The result;

```
EmpName condition
Emp1    Y
Emp2    N
```

### UPDATE

As you were told already, the *first* row has no meaning in cases where there is no explicit sort order. So the output you demand is random.

What about this:

```
SELECT m1.EmpName
      ,CASE COUNT(DISTINCT m1.Emp_cnt) WHEN 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS condition 
      ,STUFF(
        (SELECT CONCAT(', ',Emp_cnt ) FROM @mockup m2 WHERE m1.EmpName=m2.EmpName GROUP BY Emp_cnt FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'') AS Cnt_Values
FROM @mockup m1
GROUP BY m1.EmpName
```

The result:

```
EmpName condition   Cnt_Values
Emp1    Y           20
Emp2    N           20, 21, 22
```

### UPDATE 2

This is what you seem to need, but be warned: Out of my eyes this is - technically spoken - a really bad approach:

```
SELECT m1.EmpName
      ,m1.Emp_cnt
      ,CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmpName ORDER BY Emp_cnt) = 1 
            THEN (SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Emp_cnt)=1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END FROM @mockup AS m2 WHERE m2.EmpName=m1.EmpName ) 
            ELSE ''  END AS condition   
FROM @mockup m1;
```

Comment: very much appreciated but need to show in rows wise not in comma separated

Comment: @mohan111 I'm glad to help you. Just a tiny hint: If you like this, you might want to upvote. Acceptance and voting are separate steps... Thx and Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` expression with `exists` :

```
select t.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.name = t.name and t1.cnt <> t.cnt)
             then 'N' 
             else 'Y' 
        end) as condition
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done per your question with some windowed functions within common table expressions, though I cannot for the life of me work out why you want to do this...

As there is ambiguity as to what you want to do if an `EmpName` has some duplicate values but not all, that is currently treated as a `N` condition, as not "all the rows below" are duplicates:

```
declare @t table (EmpName varchar(50), Emp_cnt int);
insert into @t values('Emp1', 20),('Emp1', 20),('Emp1', 20),('Emp2', 22),('Emp2', 21),('Emp2', 20),('Emp3', 21),('Emp3', 21),('Emp3', 20);

with r as
(
    select EmpName
            ,Emp_cnt
            ,row_number() over (partition by EmpName order by Emp_cnt) as rne
            ,count(EmpName)  over (partition by EmpName, Emp_cnt order by Emp_cnt) as c
    from @t
)
,rg as
(
    select *
        ,row_number() over (order by EmpName, rne) as rn
    from r
)
select EmpName
        ,Emp_cnt
        ,case when rne = 1 and c = 3
                then 'Y'
            when rne = 1 and c = 1
                then 'N'
            else ''
            end as condition
from rg;
```

## Output

```
+---------+---------+-----------+
| EmpName | Emp_cnt | condition |
+---------+---------+-----------+
| Emp1    |      20 | Y         |
| Emp1    |      20 |           |
| Emp1    |      20 |           |
| Emp2    |      20 | N         |
| Emp2    |      21 |           |
| Emp2    |      22 |           |
| Emp3    |      20 | N         |
| Emp3    |      21 |           |
| Emp3    |      21 |           |
+---------+---------+-----------+
```